# Bibliography: Abbreviation for bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

Again, I need your help for the bibliography style my professor prescribed. In linguistics, we like to abbreviate lexicons or dictionaries using the abbreviations in inline citations and indicating them in the bibliography. It should look like this:
[image]

Till now I have the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, innamebeforetitle=true, innameidem=true, maxcitenames=2, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\slash}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hrsg\adddot},
  editors = {Hrsg\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\printorigdate}}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}
  }%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
       \global\clearfield{edition}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\sernumdelim}%
       \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@book{Battaglia,
author = {Battaglia, Salvatore},
title = {Grande dizionario della lingua italiana},
publisher = {UTET},
year = {1961--2008},
address = {Turin},
volumes = 21,
}

@book{Holtus,
editor = {Günther, Holtus and Metzeltin, Michael and Schmitt, Christian},
maintitle = {Lexikon der Romanistischen Linguistik},
title = {Kontakt, Migration und Kunstsprachen. Kontrastivität, Klassifikation und Typologie},
volume = {7},
address = {Tübingen},
publisher = {Niemeyer},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{literatur}

\begin{document}

\glqq Il participio dei verbi intransitivi coniugati con *essere* è accordato con il soggetto\grqq{} (\cite{Battaglia}: 117).\\
\dots\ (vgl. GDLI: 613).
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I’ve already taken a look to the Biblatex package manual but I don’t really know the convenient data field for "**ABBR =** author …" and neither how to show the abbreviations in inline citations.

It would be really nice if you could help me once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the field `shorthand` to give a shorthand (*Sigel*) for citations.

These `shorthands` automatically override the citation output, but they are usually not shown in the bibliography. Instead they are resolved in a dedicated list of shorthands.

```
\documentclass[french, ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Battaglia,
  author    = {Battaglia, Salvatore},
  title     = {Grande dizionario della lingua italiana},
  publisher = {UTET},
  date      = {1961/2008},
  address   = {Turin},
  volumes   = 21,
  shorthand = {GDLI},
}
@book{Holtus,
  editor    = {Günther, Holtus and Metzeltin, Michael and Schmitt, Christian},
  maintitle = {Lexikon der Romanistischen Linguistik},
  title     = {Kontakt, Migration und Kunstsprachen.
               Kontrastivität, Klassifikation und Typologie},
  volume    = {7},
  address   = {Tübingen},
  publisher = {Niemeyer},
  shorthand = {LRL7},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Battaglia,Holtus,sigfridsson}

\printbiblist{shorthand}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations, List of shorthands and references.]

If you want the list of shorthands and the bibliography combined, something like the following, where you print the `shorthand` in `begentry` might work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  innameidem=true,
  maxcitenames=2,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \printfield{shorthand}%
  \setunit*{\addspace=\space}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hrsg\adddot},
  editors = {Hrsg\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\printorigdate}}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}
  }%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
       \global\clearfield{edition}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\sernumdelim}%
       \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Battaglia,
  author    = {Battaglia, Salvatore},
  title     = {Grande dizionario della lingua italiana},
  publisher = {UTET},
  date      = {1961/2008},
  address   = {Turin},
  volumes   = 21,
  shorthand = {GDLI},
}
@book{Holtus,
  editor    = {Günther, Holtus and Metzeltin, Michael and Schmitt, Christian},
  maintitle = {Lexikon der Romanistischen Linguistik},
  title     = {Kontakt, Migration und Kunstsprachen.
               Kontrastivität, Klassifikation und Typologie},
  volume    = {7},
  address   = {Tübingen},
  publisher = {Niemeyer},
  shorthand = {LRL7},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Il participio dei verbi intransitivi coniugati con *essere* è accordato con il soggetto}
\autocite[117]{Battaglia}

Lorem \autocite{Holtus,sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: GDLI = Battaglia, Salvatore (1961–2008). Grande dizionario della lingua italiana. 21 Bde. Turin: UTET.]

---

Note the use of the `date` field in ISO 8601 format instead of `year` in `Battaglia`.

Comment: Dear @moewe, could you please again help out with something? It’s a minor modification but I couldn’t find any answers so far. I just need the alphabetic sorting to refer to the shorthand and not to the author. For example, if there is a shorthand ‘A‘ but the author is called Z, than it will be listed in the end (taking in count the author’s name Z), but I need it to be at the beginning (taking in count the shorthand). Thank you a lot for your time!

Comment: @GustaveFlaubert Please ask a new question with a suitable example document.